# Optimal value of concurrency for jms container

Tags: jms, messaging, spring-jms

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
    connection-factory="testConnectionFactory"
    acknowledge="auto"
    concurrency="10">
    <jms:listener destination="test_queue" ref="testRequestHandler" method="getMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

So, i have jms connection factory defined with concurrency set to 10 and my consumer can consume 10 messages concurrently at a time. Now, the problem is producer is queuing messages faster than consumer can consume, as a result half of my messages are getting expired in the queue.

1. I can increase message TTL so that they remain longer in queue without expiring.
2. Increase concurrency value for concurrent consumers.

The problem I'm facing is:

1. I don't know how increasing concurrency value will affect the system?
2. To what value i can increase its value? Is the concept is similar to no.of threads in thread pool?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking for some numbers there should be value to start with and max I can go upto based on system resources right? or this can only be found by repeated performance runs?

Comment: If you're looking for *optimal* values as your question indicates then you can only get those through performance testing as my answer outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you're going to reach an optimal value is by:

- Establishing clear performance goals (e.g. in terms of message throughput). Without clear goals performance tuning can turn into an endless exercise with diminishing relative improvements.
- Developing a benchmark which mimics your real-world data-set and application environment.
- Carefully running your benchmark with different configuration settings and recording the results. In this step I strongly recommend profiling your application in order to identify bottlenecks. The bottleneck will clarify where you should focus your tuning efforts.

Nobody on the Internet is going to be able to just give you an optimal value. There are too many variables at work.

Lastly, one option you didn't list was imposing flow-control on your producers to limit the amount of messages they can send so that the consumers keep up and you don't get a lot of expired messages. Most modern message brokers provide flow-control to push back on producers so they don't overwhelm them.

Comment: The problem is my service is standalone consumer and it can not really control the behavior of producers. What i really wanted if there is a number I can start with based on no.of resources (CPU) i have or I have to just start with a number and keep on increasing it till performance keep on improving?

Comment: You first need to figure out what the bottleneck is. Profile your app.

Comment: The bottle neck is my service is getting burst of messages at irregular interval of time which makes my consumers busy for a while and hence messages get expired in queue.

Comment: My hunch is that the basic act of just receiving the messages is not the real issue, but rather the work which the consumers are actually doing which is taking enough time that messages expire. Your consumer code could be doing *anything* which is one reason why nobody can just give you an optimal number for concurrency. I recommend you follow the steps outlined in my answer.

Comment: Also, the flow-control that I discussed in my answer is not something which the consumers enforce on the producers in order to control them. It's something the *broker* enforces on the producers.